# Jacoco Show Source Code

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, jacoco

I have some code which reads the `exec` file and creates html pages for all of my projects running on a webspehre server. The server is on a remote machine, I have all the source code running on the remote machine copied to my local machine. I need to know how, with the html file generated and the exec file how I can view the source code.

Is this even possible?

Comment: how are you generating your `exec` file?  what build tool? or is it command line invocation?

Comment: and just checking that drilling down to the method level and then clicking on the method name link doesn't show you the color coded source code?

Comment: The exec is gathered from source code found on the jacoco site, I am fairly certain it has to do with the workspace and the source not being available

Comment: How are you invoking jacoco ON YOUR OWN CODE to make a new `exec` file?  are you running `ant` or `maven` etc?

Comment: to be honest, I am not sure. It is a utility class called from a unit test which is a maven project. But nothing in the pom deals with jacoco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To successfully create coverage reports with Jacoco from Maven you should add the jacoco maven plugin to your POM.

As explained on the [Jacoco Maven Plugin page](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/maven.html) you need to add the plugin (with the latest version as of this posting):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
</plugin>
```

And then you need to add extra configuration to tell jacoco what phase to instrument tests and then when to generate the reports

This configuration was taken from one of the [example jacoco pom](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/examples/build/pom.xml)s for a JAR project that runs JUnit tests under code coverage and creates a coverage report (target/site/jacoco/index.html).

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>default-report</id>
        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>report</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>default-check</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>check</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <!-- implementation is needed only for Maven 2 -->
            <rule implementation="org.jacoco.maven.RuleConfiguration">
              <element>BUNDLE</element>
              <limits>
                <!-- implementation is needed only for Maven 2 -->
                <limit implementation="org.jacoco.report.check.Limit">
                  <counter>COMPLEXITY</counter>
                  <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                  <minimum>0.60</minimum>
                </limit>
              </limits>
            </rule>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: yes, I have seen that, was hoping for a solution which could be implemented in a class or series of classes, but I will keep this in mind as I move forward with this project.